# What's the right way to :reload and run :main as a single command in GHCi?

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

Is there a way to chain `:reload/:r` along with `:main` as a single command in GHCi?

The goal here is to avoid typing both every time I change something in my other terminal, but to just type <kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`:cmd` seems to accept string with multiple lines.
Therefore you can do the following command.

```
:cmd return $ unlines [":reload",":main"]
```

also you can add following code to `~/.ghci`

```
:def hoge const $ return $ unlines [":reload",":main"]
```

now you can execute `:hoge` in ghci

Comment: `hoge`? Don't you mean `doge`?

Comment: `hoge` is one of the metasyntactic variable (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable) which is often used in japanese.

Comment: You can extend this to `:cmd return $ unlines ["kt",":reload","kt <- forkAndKill"]` where `forkAndKill` forks some action then returns a thread kill action. This is useful for single command server restarting.

Comment: @ymonad for `:def` example I am getting `Variable not in scope` errors for the symbols: const, return, $, unlines. How do I import them?

Comment: @RăzvanFlaviusPanda They are in `Prelude` module, which is normally loaded by default. Maybe you can try `import Prelude` or `:module +Prelude` before :def